# Fetching stream (me/home) omits videos

Tags: facebook-graph-api, video, stream

I'm trying to get all of the videos of my stream.

When I go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ and click on the news feed (me/home) link, using that access token, I see my entire stream, including videos.

However, when I fetch the stream (me/home) from my app, it shows me the entire stream *except* the ones with type:video.  I also tried it in the graph explorer and I have the exact same problem there.  In my app, I've tried enabling permissions including user_status, user_videos, user_photo_video_tags, friends_status, friends_videos, friends_photo_video_tags, read_stream, and offline_access.  None of these help.

I even tried turning on every single permission and it doesn't help.  (If I just want to get my own videos--me/posts--that works fine.)

I also tried FQL and, while I'm a beginner at that, it seems to have the same problem.

So, can others see videos in me/home?  Am I missing something obvious?  Or is it a facebook bug?  (I couldn't find that in their bug DB).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be a bug.  You should go there and mark that you can validate it.  Also subscribe to the bug so you know when it get's fixed.

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/231621496918030

> Steps to Reproduce:   1. get an access token using the read_stream
>   permission
>
> 1. call me/home api
>
> https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?format=json&limit=25&until=1326865528&access_token=AAAEVaIcG7E0BADwZCmtcqokmLMikQqAIcE5zaUgZCtXEVlOTRVma18db7M9WWr1EcjNZAAzVhAK7LgSrGjTOlGqF3SDrMSnk4BHP3ZBC5gZDZD
>
> no data returned, but when I switched to the Graph API Explorer app in
>   the test tool with the same permission. it returns 25 entries.
>   Expected Behavior:    all feed posts in the stream Actual Behavior:   none
>   or a few entries